# How to make every video element to appear in the same size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video

I have built a video call platform using the Twilio API with ReactJs. The problem is when two people enter the room as one from desktop and one from mobile, the one that is on mobile appears as zoomed in that is happening because on my video element I have `width` set to `100%`. I want my layout to always be like whereby.com or google meets.

This is my code for rendering the participants

```
<div className="room">
      <div className="local-participant">
        {room ? (
          <Participant
            key={room.localParticipant.sid}
            participant={room.localParticipant}
            handleAudioToggle={handleAudioToggle}
            handleVideoToggle={handleVideoToggle}
            handleCallDisconnect={handleCallDisconnect}
            toggleAudio={toggleAudio}
            toggleVideo={toggleVideo}
            isLocal={true}
            isSharingScreen={toggleScreenShare}
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="remote-participants">{remoteParticipants}</div>
      <Controls
          handleCallDisconnect={handleCallDisconnect}
          handleAudioToggle={handleAudioToggle}
          handleVideoToggle={handleVideoToggle}
          handleScreenToggle={handleScreenToggle}
          audio={toggleAudio}
          video={toggleVideo}
          screen={toggleScreenShare}
        />
    </div>
```

This is my code for creating video elements

```
<div>
    <div className="futura-20-900 margin-top-8 margin-left-8" style={{ color: "white" }}>{participant.identity}</div>
      <video ref={screenRef} autoPlay={true} style={{ display: `${isSharingScreen ? 'block' : 'none'}`}}/>
      { webcamEnabled ? <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay={true} /> : <div><img src={NoCam} /></div> }
      <audio ref={audioRef} autoPlay={true} />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the required width on `video-container`. The height will set automatically to the ratio 16:9.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video ref={...} autoPlay={true} />
</div>
```

with this css

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 80vw; /* set your width here in vw */
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
.video-container::before {
    padding-top: 56.25%; /* video W:H 16:9 */
}
.video-container video,
.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```